# Conda: The following packages are missing from the target environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, aws-cli

I'm trying to uninstall awscli:

```
conda list | grep aws
awscli                    1.18.78                  pypi_0    pypi

(base) % conda remove awscli
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - awscli
```

But for some reason `conda` can't find package. What is proper way to uninstall awscli?

Comment: Um, have you tried `pip uninstall awscli`?

Answer (score 25):

### Use Pip

The channel value of `pypi` indicates that this package was installed from PyPI using `pip`, and therefore - as suggested in @Sraw's comment - it needs to be removed with `pip`.

```
pip uninstall awscli
```

---

#### Additional Tips

Using `pip` in your **base** is discouraged. See ["*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*"](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

The `conda list` command accepts a regex, so you don't need `grep` (which ends up filtering out the header information) to search specific packages. In this case `conda list aws` would have sufficed.

Comment: What if there is no pypi in the channel value, but you get the same error behavior? I definitely installed via conda, but the remove doesn't work. Here's my conda list: plotly-orca               1.2.1                         1    plotly

Comment: @areyoujokingme not sure without more info. Ask a new question will all the details. Feel free to ping me here if you want me to look at it.